# Attach a pdf in asset pipeline using ActionMailer Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, actionmailer

I'm trying to attach a file to an email. The file is in `assets/downloads/product.pdf`

In the mailer, I have:

```
attachments["product.pdf"] = File.read(ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("product.pdf"))
```

I've tried:

```
attachments["product.pdf"] = File.read(ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_url("product.pdf"))
```

...and even:

```
attachments["product.pdf"] = File.read(ActionController::Base.helpers.compute_asset_host("product.pdf") + ActionController::Base.helpers.compute_asset_path("product.pdf"))
```

I always get the same error:

```
EmailJob crashed!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - //localhost:3000/assets/product.pdf
```

...or a variation on the theme. But even when I try using asset_url in the view or just put the url in the browser it works:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/product.pdf
```

I've also tried using straight up:

```
File.read("app/assets/downloads/product.pdf")
File.read("downloads/product.pdf")
```

...which works in dev environment but not on staging server (heroku). Error is still:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - downloads/product-market-fit-storyboard.pdf
```

Also tried:

```
File.read("/downloads/product.pdf")
File.read("http://lvh.me:3000/assets/product.pdf")
```

...don't work at all.

Ideas?

Comment: try by prefixing `http` protocol while attaching the file

Comment: No go. Also tried using `File.read("http://lvh.me:3000/assets/product.pdf")`

Answer (score 0):

you should use syntex like this.it is work for me may be will work for you also.

```
File.open(Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/downloads/product.pdf"), "r")
```

Answer (score -1):

When using mailer, you shouldn't use assets pipline. Asset pipeline would be useful if you wanted to have link to a file inside your email. When rendering an email, action mailer has access to files in app directory.

Please read about attachments in [action mailer guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods). As you can see, you just need to pass path to a file, not url:

```
attachments['filename.jpg'] = File.read('/path/to/filename.jpg')
```

Comment: Ok, now I tried `File.read("app/assets/downloads/product.pdf")` which works in dev environment but not on staging server (heroku). I will also try placing it somewhere else now.

Comment: Now I tried `File.read("downloads/product.pdf")` which works in dev but doesn't work on staging. `File.read("/downloads/product.pdf")` does not function on dev.

Comment: Except assets sometimes need to be used by both mailers and controllers, and assets are hashed in production. this doesn't solve the real underlying issue